# One simple INNODB INSERT is slowing whole web

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb

Hello i am using **mainly MYISAM**, but i have **only one INNODB table** for storing ids with pretty simple PHP function.

I am sending this query: `insert into`system_id`() VALUES()`
And retrieve AUTOINCREMENT id with php function `mysql_insert_id();`

**That is everything what i am doing with INNODB.**

This query is slowing my whole WEB APP and it is all the time in slow query lists. This is only one INNODB table in whole app because of row locking...

Could you please guide me how can i config mySQL INNODB settings config my.cf for JUST THIS ONE INNODB query please?

Thank you.

```
CREATE TABLE `system_id` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=6956889 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: You should supply the table CREATE, the only thing we currently know about the table is that every field has a default value (and the id field's is an auto-increment).

Comment: thank you for response, create table is here: http://blindr.eu/info.txt , please dont be confused i have just converted it to myISAM because with myISAM it is going smooth...

Comment: Storing ids for what? How often is this used? This should be one of the fastest inserts possible into a table, regardless of engine used.

Comment: It is used aprox 10times per second and if it is in innodb its slow as hell and slowing whole app... i was wondering how can i edit my.cf to proper setup innodb engine for just this table

Answer (score 0):

`innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit` defaults to 1 for integrity.  Set it to 2 for speed.

Why are you using a separate table for getting the Id?  Can't you just have that `AUTO_INCREMENT` in the table that needs it?